# Porta única sendo disputada por multiplos clientes

Tags: node.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução para consumo de uma API de guaritas de condomínios em Nodejs, utilizando a biblioteca net para fazer a comunicação. A nossa aplicação faz comunicação direta com o hardware do condomínio e o meu maior problema é que ela disponibiliza apenas uma porta para comunicação (porta 9001) e precisa ser consumida por diversos clientes ...
A "porta única" é uma restrição do hardware, portanto não existe maneiras de alocar outras portas dentro do hardware de Guarita, preciso encontrar uma maneira de desenvolver do nosso lado algo que ajude os múltiplos clientes a consumirem os dados do hardware nessa única porta.

Segue o código do que foi desenvolvido até o momento:

```js
//bibliotecas do node utilizadas:

let net  = require("net");
let express = require('express');
let http    = require('http');
let cors    = require('cors');

let app         = express();
let server      = http.createServer(app);
let bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '800mb'}));

server.listen( 7979, function(){
    console.log("server listening to %j", server.address().port);
})
let client = net.createConnection(`9001`,`[link de acesso ao hardware]`)// Aqui o acesso é estabelecido na porta 9001 do hardware
 .on('error', (e) =>console.log('Erro de conexão', e)); 


client.on("connect", function(data){
 console.log(`linear conectado porta: %j`, server.address().port);
});

client.on("data", function(data){
//Resposta da API 
});

client.on("end", function(data){
 console.log(`end: `);
 console.log(data);
});

app.get("/teste", (req, res) => {
//requisição feita pelo client
});
```

Se houver necessidade eu posso disponibilizar mais partes do código (acredito que esse seja o suficiente pois o maior problema está no código da variável 'client').
Alguém conhece alguma solução?

Comment: Para o protocolo TCP isso é impossível. Internamente o soquete têm um token de conexão, o sistema operacional não permitirá que um soquete que não seja o portador do token receba os dados. Você pode tentar implementar um proxy (tunel) para acesso à porta, mas vai ter que adaptar seus aplicativos e será necessário um hardware entre a máquina e os clientes. (

Comment: @Edney Entendo, dessa maneira existe algum material que eu possa ler para me informar melhor sobre essa questão do proxy? Será que eu poderia fazer o proxy apenas para o uso dessa função ou tudo o que eu desenvolvi deverá ser consumido através desse proxy?

Comment: Basicamente você vai ter que fazer um aplicativo que recebe solicitações e faz o trabalho que for preciso na porta 9001, ele pode ter mecanismo de autorização, certificado, cache, etc. etc. Esse proxy vai atuar como gateway do seu recurso, mas sem saber melhor o seu ambiente não dá para dizer nada além disso. Te recomendo pesquisar sobre soquetes e protocolos, estudar procolocos comuns como http, ftp, ssl para se ter uma base. Isso dá mais trabalho do que parece. Um [exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS)